# Demonstration of processing a queue of no-op threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, queue

I am creating a script, that will SSH to several hosts, get stuff, parse it and return. Because I wait for server response, I'm using `threading`.

Real script is more complex, so I created this simple program to demonstrate logic.

In real application 'timer' function does ssh with `paramiko` and parsing, 'main' is pretty much same.

Do I need to use `threading.Lock()` in this program?

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import random
import queue

'''
This function demonstrates usage of threads with queue
'''

que = queue.Queue()


def timer(name, delay, que):  # timer's name, time.sleep() delay, queue.Queue() object
    time.sleep(delay)  # sleep

    que.put(name + " is done after " + str(delay) + " seconds")  # add items to queue, used when threaded
    return name + " is done after " + str(delay) + " seconds"  # this is used if fuction is called directly


def main(repeat):
    threads = []  # stores threads after they are started. needed to join threads
    out = []      # used for return
    for i in range(1, repeat):  # Will loop few times, executing threads
        t = Thread(target=timer, args=(('timer' + str(i)), random.choice([2, 3, 2]), que))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()        # Join is needed so that main function waits for threads. We need this to return out list

    while not que.empty():      # At this point threads are completed and joined. so we can dequeue que variable
        out.append(que.get())

    print("main completed")
    return out


start_time = time.time()        # To measure time
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('\n'.join(main(30)),)
print("--- Done in %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: You should preferably not generalize code, this makes it harder to review.

Answer (score 2):

You could skip the `join` loop here

```
for t in threads:
    t.join()

while not que.empty():      
    out.append(que.get())
```

and let `Queue.get` wait instead:

```
for _ in range(len(threads)):
    out.append(que.get())
```

And no, you don't need an explicit `threading.Lock` in *this* program because `Queue` handles the synchronization.

Note that `for i in range(1, repeat)` loops `repeat-1` times, which is probably not what you meant.

Comment: Yep, join is redundant. I used it to make main() will wait for threads, but it will wait for dequeue anyway. Thanks